# Images requested by Flask are not shown at once

Tags: http, flask

When applying the image showcase function named "twentytwenty", the following problem occurs.

**Problem:** 
When I call render_template() with the resulting image as an argument, the image is not visible.
And when I resize the internet browser window or click the refresh button, the resulting image appears.

**desired results**
It is difficult to determine the cause of the current problem. Isn't there a way to see the image right away without refreshing the internet browser or resizing the window?

**Development Environment**
I'm running code on a VM based on the Compute engine service on the Google cloud platform. The code is written in python and flask, and it is deployed to be able to access the web server externally using docker.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in the link below and solved it.

https://github.com/zurb/twentytwenty/issues/39